# Elastic Search: Query the given index to find out values fields

Tags: java, elasticsearch, nosql

Can anyone help me in making a query for the following index..

```
"_index": "demodata",
"_type": "sarthak",
"_id": "AVyLnJgOVAC1tB7BveyG",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"values": """[{"label":"Male","value":"m","selected":true},{"label":"Female","value":"F"},{"label":"Other","value":"O"}]""",
"name": "select-1496990862221",
"className": "form-control",
"label": "Select",
"type": "select",
"required": true
```

I want to get inside values and get the label ,value and selected values.Also the values are not fixed they will change. Si I want a query which works on other types. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

it's a nested field, something like this should work :

```
“must”: [
        {
           “nested”: {
              “path”: “values”,
              “filter”: {
                 “terms”: {
                    “values.label”: [
                       “male”
                    ]
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     ]
```

This query works for ES 1.7.*, you might need a little modification if you work with other versions.

Comment: Okay..see the problem is you are specifying field value, but i want a query where I will write the field name and it display the values.

Comment: That's not what I've understood. Are you looking to have the different values that a field have ?